# How to click on the label with text Boy within https://www.sneaksup.com/register using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to get data from the txt file line by line. The program does not continue to run after the email line. How can I fix this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

def slow_type(element: WebElement, text: str, delay: float=0.1):
    """Send a text to an element one character at a time with a delay."""
    for character in text:
        element.send_keys(character)
        time.sleep(delay)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.sneaksup.com/register")


with open('Gmail.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for l in lines:

    browser.get("https://www.sneaksup.com/register")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='FirstName']").send_keys("Baran")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='LastName']").send_keys("Baran")

    sif = "187400Baran*"
    sifre = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Password']")
    slow_type(sifre, sif)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Phone']")
    text = "5511939262"
    slow_type(el, text)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Email']").send_keys(l)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[6]/div/div/span[1]/label").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DateOfBirthDay']/option[14]").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DateOfBirthMonth']/option[6]").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DateOfBirthYear']/option[93]").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='AcceptKVKK']").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register-button']").click()
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Which `<label>` do you want to click?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there. If you were targetting the item with text as ***Boy*** then instead of the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[6]/div/div/span[1]/label
```

you just need to replace `div[5]` with `div[4]` as:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[6]/div/div/span[1]/label
```

Screenshot:

[image: div4]

---

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='gender-male']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='gender-male']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```